# Property date must be a valid Date error, when using jquery UI plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I have a `tasks` class, which has a `date` field. In my view file, I have this line of code :

```
<g:textField name="date" value="${tasksInstance?.date}" id="datePicker" />
```

And using the jquery ui plugin, I added this code to my `<head>` tag :

```
<g:javascript>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#datePicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
})
</g:javascript>
```

But when I save the `date` field, I get the following error:

```
Property date must be a valid Date error
```

### Edit:

`Tasks.groovy`

```
package mnm.schedule

class Tasks {
    static belongsTo = [ user : User, project: Project ]
        String reason
        boolean completed
        String title
        String description 
                Date date
        static constraints = {
            user(nullable:false)
            completed(nullable:true)
            title(nullable:false)
            description(size:1..500,nullable:false)
                reason(nullable:true)
        }
        String toString(){
                this.title
        }
}
```

And controller action code is :

```
def save() {
        def adminProject = params.managersProject
        def foundProject = Project.findByNameLike("$adminProject")
        def tasksInstance = new Tasks(params)
        foundProject.addToTasks(tasksInstance)
        if (!tasksInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [tasksInstance: tasksInstance])
            return
        }
        redirect(action: "show", id: tasksInstance.id)
    }
```

How to recover from this?

Comment: Can you show your domain object and controller code as well?

Comment: @tim_yates: ya I have edited the question

Comment: I am getting this problem when using null value even when property is setted as nullable true and blank true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're getting a String like `'02/16/2012'`?  You could just call:

```
params.date = Date.parse( 'MM/dd/yyyy', params.date )
```

Before creating the Task object...

There's probably an automatic way of doing this in Grails as well using `PropertyEditorSupport`

---

#### Edit

Also, in grails 2.0, you can do:

```
def date = params.date( 'myVar', 'MM/dd/yyyy' )
```

To parse the date param out of the params object

Comment: oh thanks sir, this works. And even I have heard about `PropertyEditorSupport`. Before posting this question, I have tried this link : http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-1-1-1-change-in-binding-date-properties-td1323105.html. This link suggest to add some `bean` in `resources.groovy` file. And in grails 2.0 where to place that `beans` property? Create a new file named `resources.groovy` under `grails-app/config/spring/` and place it there or we need to place in `config.groovy`?

Comment: probably still in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`.  Yeah if it doesn't exist, but grails creates that file by default.

Comment: @tim_yates , I have got same problem. I am trying to follow your solution. This snippet  " params.date = Date.parse( 'MM/dd/yyyy', params.date ) " will be included in save action or at top of class.  If I want to use ,def date = params.date( 'myVar', 'MM/dd/yyyy' ). what is 'myVar'?

Comment: @VSiingh it's the name of the field on the html form. `params.date( 'myVar', 'MM/dd/yyyy' )` should give the same as `Date.parse( 'MM/dd/yyyy', params.myVar )`

Comment: params.date = Date.parse( 'MM/dd/yyyy', params.date ) working for me. thanks @tim_yates

Answer (score -3):

It seems this format does'nt supported with jquery change date format