# Property startDate must be a valid Date error in Grails

Tags: validation, grails

I'm facing the same problem as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306515/property-date-must-be-a-valid-date-error-when-using-jquery-ui-plugin), but when I tired what in the solution , I'm still getting the same error:

> Property startDate must be a valid Date  Property endDate must be a
>   valid Date

Here is my domain :

```
class EmpRef {
    String workName
    String title
    Date   startDate
    Date   endDate
    String reasonForLeaving
    String directMgrName
    String directMgrTitle
    String directMgrTelephone
}
```

Here is my save action :

```
def save(EmpRef empRefInstance) {
    empRefInstance.startDate=Date.parse('dd-MM-yyyy',params.startDate)
    empRefInstance.endDate=Date.parse('dd-MM-yyyy',params.endDate)
    if (empRefInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (empRefInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond empRefInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    empRefInstance.save flush:true
}
```

the jQuery code in the GSP:

```
$('.datePicker').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    autoSize: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    maxDate: "0y",
    showAnim: "show",
    yearRange:'c-70:c+0'
});
```

Comment: dd-MM vs dd-mm tried to see what the difference is ? month vs minutes

Answer (score 0):

If `EmpRef` is argument of a method, it is automatically binded on request. This causes both `startDate` and `endDate` to have error. After you set values on those columns, you need to execute `empRefInstance.validate()` instead of `empRefInstance.hasErrors()` to get new validation result in domain.

Also because you check `empRefInstance` for null **after** you set start and end date you will get NullPointerException on previous lines if this object is null, so check for null should be done earlier in the code

Comment: when i was doing debugging i found that `startDate` and `endDate` are `null ` in `empRefInstance` although it supposed to be set here `<input  type="text" class='datePicker' name='startDate' >`, what may cause this ?

Comment: are those `null` in `params.startDate` ?

Comment: no `params.startDate` and `params.endDate` are not null , startDate and endDate  were null when i print `empRefInstance.properties`

Comment: also i found after parsing the startDate its value is `Sun May 01 00:00:00 EEST 2016` although the format is `dd-MM-yyyy` , so i think the problem is in the parsing.

Comment: `empRefInstance` has empty properties because binding failed. You can set format on domain/command properties which should be used to parse value from client - check `Date Formats For Data Binding` chapter in documentation. Also if value you send looks like that it will not work, you have to set correct format on client side